# Late Answers audits should show comments

Tags: discussion, user-interface, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

I just failed [this Late Answers audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4539151), where the answer by itself appears a reasonable self-answer, but it was apparently downvoted because, commenters alleged, it was a duplicate of an existing answer; there was apparently no problem with the content itself.

There's no way to identify issues like these when comments are hidden and the audit system lies about the answer score; I'm not sure about all of the tradeoffs, but showing comments for LA reviews seems superficially reasonable.

Comment: Even if the answer was copied it should be ok.  As per the chat discussion several hours back, I was told that the content on the site is licensed [CC](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and it is ok to copy/paste stuff even to the extent of making other answers appear redundant.

Comment: That discussion is available [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89).  So it was _pointless_ to downvote the answer to begin with.  The users ought to be penalised.  After all, the answer suggested to move the logic to _Shown_ event and the so-called-copied answer mentioned changing it to _Activated_ event.

Comment: That's an odd case. It received a "not an answer" flag, but I don't think a moderator would have accepted that and deleted the answer as a result. Instead, the user themselves deleted their answer, which immediately marked that flag as being helpful and made this a potential audit candidate. That doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: I'm voting to undelete the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22796840/2235132).

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794904/vb-net-show-hide-buttons-depending-on-variable-value#comment34762903_22796840) gives more insight how _not-so-new_ users on the site act  (post deleted - 10K+ only).